# rails fetching only true boolean objects in model instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, boolean

I am currently fetching all notes in model by

```
@notes_list = current_user.notes.order(:title).group_by { |note| note.title[0] }
```

Later i added a column to **notes** table that is **known** a **boolean** column.

Now i want to fetch only true valued columns and false valued columns separately something like below

```
@notes_true_list = blah....
@notes_false_list = blah....
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
@notes_true_list = current_user.notes.where(known: true).order(:title).group_by { |note| note.title[0] }

@notes_false_list = current_user.notes.where(known: false).order(:title).group_by { |note| note.title[0] }
```